# Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I use DomCrawler in Symfony.

```
$variable = 'value';
$crawler->filter('table > tr')->each(
    function ($node, $i) {
        // $variable;
    }
);
```

I try to access the variable inside the function but I get the error: Undefined variable.

How can I call this variable inside the function?

Comment: Please read the [manual](https://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `use` statement for injecting var from parent scope:

```
$variable = 'value';
$crawler->filter('table > tr')->each(
     function ($node, $i) use ($variable) {
           // $variable;
     }
);
```